# How to delegate the balance of a smart contract?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, delegating

I am looking to create a smart contact that will delegate the funds it is storing.

1) How does an originated KT address delegate to a baker? 
2) If a KT address delegates, can it do anything else?

I haven't been able to find any example contracts. I am learning to develop in smartpy but will take any guidance I can get regardless of language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How does an originated KT address delegate to a baker?

During the origination of a smart contract, an initial delegate can be set. After origination, only the smart contract itself can change its delegate and it does that by calling the [`SET_DELEGATE`](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#instr-SET_DELEGATE) Michelson instruction (called `sp.set_delegate` in SmartPy).

> 2) If a KT address delegates, can it do anything else?

Yes, delegation does not affect the behavior of a smart contract.

Answer (score 1):

As of 005, KT1s are not necessary for delegation. A KT1 can only have 1 code block, which it receives automatically when you delegate a KT1 (just use any wallet or the CLI to initiate this). So, KT1 can only do one thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it with a proper contract, use `sp.set_delegate` to set or unset the delegate of a smart contract funds. https://www.smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_key_hash.